# File gets stuck on mouse

Tags: macos, mac, mouse, macbook

When dragging a file with an external mouse the file just gets stuck on the mouse. I cannot drag the file at all with the touchpad on the MacBook and have tried going into Accessability Settings and enabled the dragging settings

[image]

Comment: Enabled which dragging settings? A screenshot would be useful. What mouse is it? Does it have its own control panel?

Comment: It doesn't have its own control panel and this occurs with all external mice. I will attach a screenshot to the post @Tetsujin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple suggested clearing my NVRAM which solved my issue and it has yet to come back.

Answer (score 0):

There is a temporary fix from https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4169871:

- reboot mac
- put mac in sleep mode
- wake it up
- issue will be fixed

It helped me with High Sierra/Mojave yesterday.